# Get and display category name by category description

Tags: categories

Now i use this code for get display category name:

```
$idObj = get_category_by_slug('products');
$id = $idObj->term_id;
echo get_cat_name($id);
```

But i need to get category name by description.

How to get and display **category name** by category **description**?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a built-in function like "get_cat_name_by_desc()", but you can use the `description__like` [parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) along with `get_categories()` or `get_terms()`:

```php
$cats = get_categories( [
  'description__like' => 'foo desc',
  'hide_empty'        => false, // disabled for testing purposes
] );
echo isset( $cats[0] ) ? $cats[0]->name : 'No categories found.';
```